# Display a few lines before selected word

Tags: sed, awk, grep

The following command is correctly returning all the lines with warnings more than 0 from all files.

```
grep -i warning * | grep -v 'Warnings: 0' | more
```

I want to see the 4 lines above the warnings line where warning is more than 0. The -B4 switch does not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: What are those obvious reasons? I'm guessing that it is because you don't care about the actual `Warnings: 0` line or anything between, but you should really clarify

Comment: I mean this does not work # grep -iB4 warning * | grep -v 'Warnings: 0' | more

Comment: WHAT doesn't work about it? Does it give you an error (what error)? Is the output not what you expected (and in what way)? Does your computer catch fire? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, here is a solution:

```
grep -v "Warnings: 0" * | grep -B4 -i warning
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You have a missing *, please add it to your answer. # grep -v "Warnings: 0" * | grep -B4 -i warning

Answer (score 1):

How about using a little regex instead:

```
grep -e "Warnings: [1-9][0-9]*" -B4 * | more
```

The grep should look for 1 or more warnings and print the previous 4 lines.

Comment: # doesn't OR in reg exp work? # grep -e "('Warnings: [1-9][0-9]*' | '[1-9][0-9]* warning')" -B9 * | more

Comment: @shantanuo: Try using `grep -E` or `egrep` for this, it provides an extended set of POSIX syntax. Then you can use the `|` OR operator

Answer (score 0):

your are unclear if the warnings message should be include in the output or not.
In this version it is.

Try:

```
awk -F"[: ]" '($1  /Warning/ && $2> 0){a[NR]=$0;for (i=4;i>=0;i--) \
            print a[NR-i]}{a[NR]=$0}' file
```

HTH Chris